# Set custom dialog once into activity

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have listactivity consist of multiple row each row open activity which contain text and two button one of them open infinite gallery the other one open dialog ,and each dialog had different string ,

i have 20 row so i add dialog 20 times which is redundant , also its work fine but i think there is better approach than what i did  ,

any help to get it will be appreciated , thanks

**MyDay class:**

```
public class MyDay extends Activity {
final Context context = this;
private Button button;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;
String day;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.Layou
          tParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    Boolean customTitleSupported =       
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);     
    setContentView(R.layout.day);  

    if (customTitleSupported) {          
     getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title);  } 

    initializeTextViews(); }

private void initializeTextViews() {
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_tv1); 
    tv1.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day_tv1);
    tv2.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

    tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day_tv3);
    tv3.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

     day=getIntent().getStringExtra("cheese");

    if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day1")){
        tv1.setText("First Day");       
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));  
        tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day1))); 

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);        
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
      public void onClick(View arg0) { 
        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.cust_dialog);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);           
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); 
        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
        text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));                
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_1)));

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);             
                dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();}
                         });
                dialog.show(); }
                         }); }

     else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day2")){
        tv1.setText("Second Day");
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
        tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day2))); 

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);        
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
          public void onClick(View arg0) {   
            // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.cust_dialog);                  
                 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);          
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);  

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);               
              text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));              
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_2)));

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);         
         dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss(); }
                            });  
                    dialog.show(); }
                        }); }
     else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day3")){
        tv1.setText("Third Day");
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
        tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day3))); 

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);        
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
          public void onClick(View arg0) {   
        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.cust_dialog);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);           
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);                  
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);               
                  text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));              
               text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_3)));

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);             
            dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        ialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss(); }
                            });  
                    dialog.show(); }
                        }); 
                                   }
                                 }

  // this continuing repeated till day 20 // 

 public void handleClick(View v){

    //Create an intent to start the new activity.

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this,DayGallery.class);
    intent.putExtra("dayname",day);
    startActivity(intent);

                  }
            }
```

Comment: I was unable to figure out what's your issue or what do you want achieve

Comment: @blackbelt my code work perfectly but i repeat the dialog for each day so repeated around 20 times, the below answer of TronicZomB working well but one thing still , with my code i was able to change color of some words in dialog by apply :<b><font color=#6B8E23> in (strings.xml) now i cant do it all dialog words take one color which assigned in xml layout, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of duplicating code. I suggest change  intent day indicating extra type to int, and put your text resources into arrays with index = day number - 1.

Also it is easier to read and maintain code if you implement onClickListener interface in your activity class instead of creating new object.

Here is refactored version of your code, much shorter and clearer:

```
public class MyDay extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Context mContext = this;
    private Button mButton;
    private TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4;
    private int  dayNumber;
    private Dialog mDialog;
    // this string should be in resources, like other below
    private final String[] tv1Resources = {"First day", "Second day", "Third day" , ...}; 
    private final int[] tv3Resources = {R.string.day1, R.string.day2, R.string.day3 , ...};
    private final int[] dialogTextResources = {R.string.torusim_places_1, R.string.torusim_places_2, R.string.torusim_places_3 , ...};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        Boolean customTitleSupported =       
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);     
        setContentView(R.layout.day);  

        if (customTitleSupported) {          
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title);  } 

            // note, now you should put integer extra, 
            //not String, this extra is just day number -1, 
            //for day1 this is 0, for day2 this is 1 etc. 
            //In your case, probably this number == item position in listview of 
        dayNumber = getIntent().getIntExtra("cheese", -1); previous activity
        if (dayNumber == -1){
            finish(); //this needed if somehow you get invalid extra
            return;
        }

        initializeTextViews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        switch (v.getId()){
            //actually this switch isn't needed because you have 
            //only one button in this activity, but I wanted to show,
            // how you can maintain many onClick events here
        case R.id.city_button: 
            // custom dialog
                    // we use class field for avoid making final dialog local variable
            mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, R.style.cust_dialog); 

            mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
            text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
            text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(dialogTextResources[dayNumber])));

            Button dialogButton = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);
            dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mDialog != null) mDialog.dismiss(); // check for aviod dialog null pointer
                }
            });
            mDialog.show(); 
            break;
        }
    }

    private void initializeTextViews() {
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_tv1);
        tv1.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day_tv1);
        tv2.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));


        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day_tv3);
        tv3.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));


        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        tv1.setText(tv1Resources[dayNumber]);
         // due to code, this resource is the same for all days
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
        tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(tv3Resources[dayNumber])));
    }

    public void handleClick(View v) {
        // Create an intent to start the new activity.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, DayGallery.class);
        intent.putExtra("dayname", day);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why dont you try this solution? If you don't want to change intent extra type to int, you can find this from string day number, if extra equals day "day 1" - dayNumber =0 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your dialog creation within a separate method and just call that method from your `onClick` of your buttons. something like the following:

```
if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day1")){
    tv1.setText("First Day");       
    tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));  
    tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day1))); 

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);        
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View arg0) { 
            dialogCreation(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_1)).toString());
        }

 else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day2")){.... }
```

Then your `dialogCreation()` could look like:

```
public void dialogCreation(String arg0) {
     // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.cust_dialog);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);           
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); 
    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
    text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));                
    text.setText(arg0);

     Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);             
            dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();}
                     });
            dialog.show(); }
                     }); 
}
```

Comment: but each dialog had different string

Comment: @AndroidStack I updated my answer. You could pass in different arguments based on the if statement. I think I edited my answer correctly based on the String you mentioned.

Comment: yea, that means that you have to create the method `dialogCreation(String);` within your class that you are calling it from.

Comment: Could you post your whole class?

Comment: It seems that it is considering `Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_2)))` to be Spannable not a String. You will need to alter that part then.

Comment: Can you do a `.toString()` on your Html.fromHtml? If not then try changing the type of arg0 in the dialogCreation() to Spanned like so `public void dialogCreation(Spanned arg0)`

Comment: @AndroidStack I have updated my code in the button's onClick, check that out.

Comment: i still have problem if i close this line ( dialogCreation(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_1)).toString());) with } only , under it red line error and if i close it with }});} , i will have but i have red line error under ALL *dialogCreation* . how to solve it , please thanks.

Comment: H you should just close it as I have it then followed by }});

Comment: @TronicZomBif you can just copy my class to your eclipse and see

Comment: my dear , its work fine now but one small problem happened ,before apply your code , i customized dialog string in (strings.xml), by apply font color to some word in dialog not it seem to be not affected by font color change all appear with same color ignoring my font color changes applied as:<b><font color=#ffffff>park</b><br/> , this word park must has white color but isn't changed to white , any advice please

Comment: How about right after `text.setText(arg0);` you add in the line `text.setTextColor(Color.White);`

Comment: no i used your code exactly , my all text color is red set in xml but some word i changed its color by add this in (strings.xml),as:<string name="torusim_places_1">
 <![CDATA[  
 <b><font color=#6B8E23>This day two in city </b> london .<br/> 
 <b><font color=#6B8E23>morning </b> will go to park.<br/>
 <b><font color=#6B8E23>evening</b> will go to sea.<br/>    
  ]]> 
  </string>
so (This day two in city & morning & evening ) will be green color , the rest words will
be red color (referd red color from res-layout-custom_dialog.xml).

Comment: @ TronicZomB  also i have to be able to change many words to different colors as with my previous code, suppose i need three colors in my string

Comment: The only thing I saw was that it needed to be `new View.OnClickListener()` on your buttons.