# Dialog Ignore Font Color Html Tag

Tags: java, android, html, customdialog

I have multiple dialog in one activity and every thing run perfectly and dialog **text** 
can be

fully customized from (**string.xml**)  by adding html tags .

**Activity code :**

```
public class MyDay extends Activity {
 final Context context = this;
 private Button button;
 TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;
 String day;

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.Layou
      tParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
Boolean customTitleSupported =       
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);     
setContentView(R.layout.day);  

if (customTitleSupported) {          
 getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title);  
 } 

   initializeTextViews();
 }

private void initializeTextViews() {
 tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_tv1); 
 tv1.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

 tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day_tv1);
 tv2.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

 tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day_tv3);
 tv3.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

     day=getIntent().getStringExtra("cheese");

if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day1")){
    tv1.setText("First Day");       
    tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));  
    tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day1))); 

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);        
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
  public void onClick(View arg0) { 
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.cust_dialog);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);           
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); 
    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
    text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));                
    text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_1)));

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);             
    dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
   });
            dialog.show(); 
        }
   });
 }

 else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day2")){
    tv1.setText("Second Day");
    tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
    tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day2))); 

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);        
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
      public void onClick(View arg0) {   
        // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.cust_dialog);                  
     dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);          
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);  

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);               
    text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));              
    text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_2)));

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);         
     dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
       dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss(); 
                 }
             });  
                dialog.show();
             }
         });
       }
 else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day3")){
    tv1.setText("Third Day");
    tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
    tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day3))); 

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);        
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
      public void onClick(View arg0) {   
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.cust_dialog);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);           
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);                  
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);               
    text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));              
    text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_3)));

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);             
    dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss(); 
            }
       });  
                dialog.show();
          }
      }); 
    }
 }
                   // this continuing repeated till day 20 // 


 public void handleClick(View v){

  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setClass(this,DayGallery.class);
  intent.putExtra("dayname",day);
  startActivity(intent);

              }
        }
```

**String.xml:**

```
<string name="torusim_places_1">
<![CDATA[    
<b><font color=#008000>* </b>This is  <b><font color=#008080>First</b> line in  
    dialog <br/>
<b><font color=#ff00ff>* </b>This is  <b><font color=#FDD017>Second</b> line in  
    dialog <br/>         
<b><font color=#0000FF>* </b>This is  <b><font color=#808000>Third</b> line in 
    dialog <br/> 
<b><font color=#59C9FA>* </b>This is  <b><font color=#0000A0>Fourth</b> line in  
    dialog <br/>
  ]]> 
</string>
```

**output image :**

[image]

BUT i have 20 row so i add dialog 20 times which is redundant , its work fine but i think there is better approach than what i did ,

**So as per answer of my previous question** [Set custom dialog once into activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655404/set-custom-dialog-once-into-activity)

i applied the answered code as bellow :

```
public class MyDay extends Activity {
final Context context = this;
private Button button;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;
String day;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
Boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.day);  

 if (customTitleSupported) {             
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title); 
} 

    initializeTextViews();
    }

private void initializeTextViews() {
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_tv1); 
    tv1.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day_tv1);
    tv2.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

    tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day_tv3);
    tv3.setTypeface(FontFactory.getDroidNaskh(getBaseContext()));

           day=getIntent().getStringExtra("cheese");

    if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day1")){
        tv1.setText("First Day");       
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));  
        tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day1))); 

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);           
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
      public void onClick(View arg0) {            
        dialogCreation(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_1)).toString());
        }
     });
   }

     else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day2")){
        tv1.setText("Second Day");
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
        tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day2))); 

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);        
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
    public void onClick(View arg0) {                              
        dialogCreation(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_2)).toString());
         }
      });
     }

     else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Day3")){
        tv1.setText("Third Day");
        tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.beginning)));
        tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.day3))); 

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.city_button);        
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
    public void onClick(View arg0) {                      
        dialogCreation(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_3)).toString());
        }
     });
    }
  } 
            // this continuing repeated till day 20 // 

public void handleClick(View v){
    //Create an intent to start the new activity.
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this,DayGallery.class);
    intent.putExtra("dayname",day);
    startActivity(intent); 
            }

 public void dialogCreation(String arg0) {
       // custom dialog
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.cust_dialog);
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);           
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); 
   // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
  TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
  text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));                
  text.setText(arg0);

  Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);             
  dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
  dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
       }
  });
        dialog.show();
     }
   }
```

BUT i have one problem with answered code which is **ignorance of font color tag** with the same (**string.xml**)

so all words took one color which is set in R.layout.custom_dialog.

**String.xml:**

```
<string name="torusim_places_1">
<![CDATA[    
<b><font color=#008000>* </b>This is  <b><font color=#008080>First</b> line in  
    dialog <br/>
<b><font color=#ff00ff>* </b>This is  <b><font color=#FDD017>Second</b> line in  
    dialog <br/>         
<b><font color=#0000FF>* </b>This is  <b><font color=#808000>Third</b> line in 
    dialog <br/> 
<b><font color=#59C9FA>* </b>This is  <b><font color=#0000A0>Fourth</b> line in  
    dialog <br/>
  ]]> 
</string>
```

**output image :**

[image]

any help will be appreciated , thanks

Comment: font color='#008000', you missed '' ?

Comment: @blackbelt my above String.xml work perfectly with my code but not working when applied the answered code , also i try your comment , it gave me error , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this way: it gives to me (Samsung Galaxy Note N7000) an orange * and the "First"  word in green

```
 <string name="torusim_places_1">
     <![CDATA[<b><font color="#FF8000"> * </font></b>This is  <b><font color="#008080">First</font></b>line in  
 dialog<br />]]>
    </string>
```

Instand of a String pass the argument of dialogCreate to int:

```
  public void dialogCreation(int arg0) {
       // custom dialog
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.cust_dialog);
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);           
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); 
   // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
  TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
  text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));                
  text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getStrint(arg0));

  Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_Button);             
  dialogButton.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
  dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
       }
  });
        dialog.show();
     }
```

and call it as `dialogCreation(R.string.torusim_places_1);`

Comment: i think its not the matter of how to write tag in  string.xml but its in the class code after changed , it affect apply the font color tag , because i checked your code still the same problem there , please check updated post , images added also the same string.xml used for both codes , thanks

Comment: in order to understand where the issue is, inside dialogCreationg, change  text.setText(arg0); with  text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.torusim_places_1)); and check if it makes any difference

Comment: i changed and get the font color changed also correctly but i want to assign each torusim_places to each Day sequentially , how can i do it please , thanks

Comment: to the issmues seems related to the Spannable -> String conversion

Comment: thanks a lot my master , would you please take a look on my other question , i tried hardly to solve it but no way , thanks , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625798/listactivity-error-with-jelly-bean-running-device-span-exclusive-exclusive-spa